# How to get the second member of a stream continually? (scala)

Tags: scala, stream

Here's what I have:

```
val streams = getStreams map {stream => 
  stream.slice(stream.size-2, stream.size-1) }
```

However, `streams foreach println`  doesn't print anything.  `getStreams` works, though.

How do I continually get the second value on these streams?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `stream.hasDefiniteSize` and that returned false, so `.slice` wasn't going to work.  However, the following worked:

```
val streams = getStreams map { _.tail }
```